# How to enable mouse wheel scrolling for zooming in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have mapbox map in a website,  I can do zoom with the default buttons of the map and making click in the map but I need to enable do the zooming with the mouse wheel.

Any ideas, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The  solution is the following command line:

```
map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
```